# appending dictionary values into a list, getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I am trying to implement a basic Information Retrieval system :

```
class IRSystem:
    """A very simple Information Retrieval System. The constructor
    s = IRSystem() builds an empty system. Next, index several documents
    with s.index_document(ID, text).
    """

    def __init__(self):
        "Initialize an IR Sytem."
        self.tdf = defaultdict(set)
        self.doc_ids = []

    def index_document(self, doc_id, words):
        "Add a new unindexed document to the system."
        self.doc_ids.append(doc_id)
        for word in words:
            self.tdf[word].add(doc_id)
        return self.tdf

    def index_collection(self, filenames):
        "Index a collection of documents."
        for filename in filenames:
            self.index_document(os.path.basename(filename),
                                tokenize(open(filename).read()))

    def query(self, *terms):
        "Query the system for documents in which all terms occur."
        set_list = []
        for term in terms:
            set_list.append(self.tdf[term])
        return set.intersection(*set_list)
```

I have some problem with the `query method`. Suppose I have a collection of 3 texts. The `index_collection method`, for each file (text document) fill the `tdf dictionary` with (word,set of text in which the word appears) values.

Given a list of terms, the `query method` first create an `empty list`,then for each terms, append the co-respective value in `tdf` (that is supposed to be a set) in the initial `list`.
When I do:

```
s.index_collection(glob.glob("*.txt"))
terms = ["ora","pioggerellina","caduta"]
s.query(terms)
```

I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

The problem is here:

```
set_list.append(self.tdf[term])
```

I don't understand why this happens. `self.tdf[tems]` is a `set`, and I simply want to `append` this set to a `list`.
What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `extend`? From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: same error with extend

Comment: `s.query(*terms)` ... you need to unpack your list

Comment: `set_list.extend(list(self.tdf[term])`

Comment: for Joran: ok it works! can you explain why (sorry in the last i write that it doesnt)? thanks

Comment: You can find more information by searching for "python *args and **kwargs".